How to extend Encrypted persistence partition on Kali live USB
I would like to increase the amount of Encrypted persistence storage for my Kali Linux live USB. It is encrypted with LUKS encryption and is written as a DD image.
My USB is a Sandisk with 32GB and I only use about 2GB for Kali, so the rest is free to use.
I have done research but can’t figure out how to extend the persistence when it is encrypted and written in DD, even though I can access the system myself. This probably isn’t relevant but I burnt it with the latest Rufus version.
Anything I can try?

Your reference to "DD" isn't very clear. Did you initially follow this to install Kali (dd is used once there, is that the "DD" you refer to)? https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/usb-persistence-encryption/ ? What does lsblk show? Please edit your question to add information in it. Please use text, not screenshot.

Sorry for the confusion.
When I say DD, I mean when I used Rufus to burn the Kali Iso image I got from their website, I had the option to write as a DD image, not an Iso image, the difference being DD partitioning is more manual and less automated than Iso. Thanks very much.
When I run lsblk it shows sda1 and sda2 separately with the encryption present.

Please EDIT to add more info so everything is in the question. And pelase don't describe output, show it so we know what it is.
